# Return navbarTab name to server.r

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to have the name (or some other unique identifier) from the selected navbarPage tab (top level) be returned to the server.r file for conditional display.

A minimal example is below, where the goal is to make the selected navbarPage tab name ("NavTab1" or "NavTab2") available to the verbatimText.

ui.r :

```
navbarPage("Navbar",
       tabPanel("NavTab1",
                br(),
                verbatimTextOutput("text"),
                tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                            tabPanel("Plot 1",
                                     plotOutput("plot1")
                            )
                            )
                ),
       tabPanel("NavTab2",
                br(),
                tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                            tabPanel("Plot 2",
                                     plotOutput("plot2")
                            )
                            )
               )
       )
```

server.r:

```
function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(x=runif(10), col="blue")
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(x=runif(1000), col="red")
  }) 

  output$text <- renderText({
  RETURN NAVTAB NAME
  })
}
```

The navbarPage docs make it look like this is possible, but none of the combinations of `id` or `value` that I've tried have worked.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the name of the current navbar tab selected by setting the `id` argument of the `navbarPage()` and referencing that `input$id` in your server.  A very minimal example of this is shown below.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui=navbarPage("Navbar",id="navbar",
                tabPanel("NavTab1", verbatimTextOutput("current_tab_view1")),
                tabPanel("NavTab2", verbatimTextOutput("current_tab_view2"))
  ),
  server = function(input,output,session){
    output$current_tab_view1 <- renderText(input$navbar)
    output$current_tab_view2 <- renderText(input$navbar)
  }
)
```

### result

[image: navbareg]

Comment: Thanks.  Sloppy on my part, i was plugging `id` into tabpanel.  This works.